# Improving a "Four Fours" puzzle solver

Tags: python, math, iteration, python-itertools

```
import itertools
import math
import time
from time import time
from math import factorial
from math import sqrt


def pretty(string):
    string=string.replace("(4)","4")
    string=string.replace("factorial4","factorial(4)")
    string=string.replace("sqrt4","sqrt(4)")
    return string


def test(n):
start=time()
fails=0
for i in range(0,n+1):
    if(fours(i))!=None:
        print(fours(i))
    else:
        print("Failed: "+str(i))
        fails+=1
return("\nFailed "+str(fails)+" out of "+str(n)+"\n\nTotal time: "+str(time()-start)[:4]+"\nAverage time: "+str((time()-start)/n)[:4])

def fours(goal):
    operators = ['-','/','+','*','sqrt','^','factorial',"."]
    brackets = ["{0}{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}",
                "({0}{1}{0}){2}{0}{3}{0}",
                "({0}{1}{0}{2}{0}){3}{0}",
                "({0}{1}({0}{2}{0})){3}{0}",
                "(({0}{1}{0}){2}{0}){3}{0}",
                "{0}{1}({0}{2}({0}{3}{0}))",
                "{0}{1}(({0}{2}{0}){3}{0})",
                "({0}{1}{0}){2}({0}{3}{0})"]
    for combination in itertools.product(operators, repeat=3):
        for bracket in brackets:
            try:
                formula = bracket.format("(4)", *combination).replace(".(4","(.4")
            except ValueError:
                pass
            try:
                if eval(formula)==goal:
                    return(pretty((formula + " = " + str(int(eval(formula))))))
            except:
                pass

print(test(20))
```

Here is the code for a solver for the "Four Fours" 
puzzle.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours

It basically work, but the problem is that it can only use the + - / * operators, because it can't have two operators in a row(Solutions like this (4-4)/4+factorial(4) aren't allowed because of this "+factorial" part).What I could do(but would be to slow) would be to make pairings like this.
['-', '/', '+', '*', '-sqrt', '-^', '-factorial', '-.', '/sqrt', '/^', '/factorial', '/.', '+sqrt', '+^', '+factorial', '+.', '*sqrt', '*^', '*factorial', '*.']

This is far too many operators.

What I would like to do, would be to try something like this

```
formula = bracket.format(["(4)","(4*)","(4-)","(4/)"], *combination).replace(".(4","(.4")
```

Except this syntax is invalid.

How can I do this?

Or if you have better ideas(which I'm sure some of you do) I am open to suggestions.

Comment: separate your operators into mutually exclusive lists. Basically, any two operators that can't be used one after the other will be in the same list. Something like `['-', '+', '/', '*'] , ['sqrt', ''] ... ['-' ''], ['.', '']`. Then you can just brute force through it, applying one of each list to each term (make sure that optional operators are optional). Note the order as well, you don't want any results to have syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting it into pre or post-fix. You can allow it to use ['!','sqrt','.'] anytime. '^' would only be used if at least one four is still available to be pushed on the stack. And ['+','-','/','*'] would only be pushed if there are more operators than numbers (or something like that).